# matplotlib top bottom ticks different

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to have top ticks in and bottom tick out in matplotlib plots?
Sometimes I have data hiding ticks and I would like to set ticks out only for the side that is affected.

The following code will affect both top and bottom or both right and left.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 )
ax.plot( [0, 1, 3], 'o' )
ax.tick_params( direction = 'out' )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

With the upgrade from [#11859](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11859) for `matplotlib>=3.1.0` we can now use a [Secondary Axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html#secondary-axis) via `secondary_xaxis` and `secondary_yaxis` to achieve independent tick directions:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111 )
ax.plot( [0, 1, 3], 'o' )
ax.tick_params( direction = 'out' )
ax_r = ax.secondary_yaxis('right')
ax_t = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
ax_r.tick_params(axis='y', direction='in')
ax_t.tick_params(axis='x', direction='inout')
```

which produces this figure:

[image: Axis with independent tick directions (in/out/inout) left and right as well as top and bottom.]

Comment: You should specify which version can use this feature for me it does not work

Comment: @GM I am very sorry my answer does not meet your standards of completeness. I did link the matplotlib PR that introduces this, which flags the milestone `v3.1.0`, so my guess is you need `matplotlib>=3.1.0`. What is your matplotlib version? Does upgrading solve the issue for you?

Comment: Seems so I had matplotlib 2

Answer (score 10):

You can have twin axes, then you can set the properties for each side separately:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([0, 1, 3], 'o')

axR = ax.twinx()
axT = ax.twiny()

ax.tick_params(direction = 'out')
axR.tick_params(direction = 'in')

ax.tick_params(direction = 'out')
axT.tick_params(direction = 'in')

plt.show()
```

[image]