# Why do I feel restricted with my tick direction choices in matplotlib? (controlling separate axes)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I've played with setting tick direction in rcParams using "in", "out", turning on and off the left, right, bottom, and top ticks but I have yet to find a way to do something that seems so simple. I just want both right and left y-axes ticks to face left, and top and bottom x-axes ticks to face down.

How do I do this?
Is there a way to change the Tick objects after they have been made?

Heres a snippet of me fooling around with things I may not fully understand:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline

plt.rc("font",size=18)
plt.rc("figure",figsize=(14,3.5))
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'ytick.left': True})
rc("ytick",direction="in")
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'ytick.right': True})
rc("ytick",direction="out")
#rc("ytick.major",left=True)
#rc("ytick.major",right=True)
#plt.rc("ytick",left=False)

# test
y = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,4,23,23,34,3]
x = [i for i in range(len(y))]
plot(x,y)
```

Right now I'm trying to do this in a Jupyter notebook.

EDIT: I have found a fairly acceptable solution and put it in the comments.

Comment: matplotlib 2.0.0 was released last month, maybe it has new options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib top bottom ticks different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884335/matplotlib-top-bottom-ticks-different)

Answer (score 0):

So after some tinkering and input from clever colleagues, my best solution was this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as aa
% matplotlib inline

y = array([3,2,4,5,7,8])
x = [i for i in range(len(y))]

fig = plt.figure()

#*********************************************************
#****************** Here's the magic**********************
#*********************************************************
ax = aa.Subplot(fig,111) # 1 row, 1 column, 1st plot
fig.add_subplot(ax)

ax.axis["bottom","left"].major_ticks.set_tick_out(True)
ax.axis["bottom","left"].minor_ticks.set_tick_out(True)
ax.axis["top","right"].major_ticks.set_tick_out(False)
ax.axis["top","right"].minor_ticks.set_tick_out(False)

#*********************************************************

ax.plot(x,y)
ax.plot(x,y2)
#ax.set_ylim(0,30)
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_xscale("log")
```

[tickCtrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h8xB.png)

The important part seems to be using axisartist to create the subplot, because when I try to use "plt.subplots()" I get errors when trying to call axis["bottom"].

This is strange to me, because I think axisartist is always used to draw axes with matplotlib. I'd love to hear a more detailed explanation by someone who has a more thorough understanding than me.